# Bootstrap: using both the top and bottom fixed navbar for different widths

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, navbar

At the moment I am in a fight with my Bootstrap navbars. 
For devices with the max width of 767px I want a nav bar fixed at the bottom of the screen. All bigger devices must have a nav bar fixed to the top. I have read some related questions in the community and it helped me somehow but not answered my question yet.

Version: Bootstrap 3.3.6
Version: Dreamweaver CC 2015

Using media queries for my question should be the answer but I don't know how. If I am correct, the following code should do the job(correct me if I am wrong):

```
.no-overflow{
    display:none;
}
```

The thing I need to know is, how do I properly insert the media query in my nav bar code:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) { 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
color: #ffffff;
background-color: #d35500;
}
```

HTML code bottom-fixed:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bottomFixedNavbar1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a></div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bottomFixedNavbar1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You just need a close bracket :

```
@media (max-width: 767px) { 
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #ecf0f1;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #d35500;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it is not the answer. I forgot to paste the last bracket.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your HTML looks like but you want to do something like this

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    /* This select may need to changed */
    .navbar.navbar-fixed-top {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added my HTML code in the question above. If I copy your code and add it in my css file nothing chances in 'preview in browser'(Dreamweaver CC 2015). Do you have an other solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer myself (with the help of the community). I am going to post it so it might help others.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {

  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #ecf0f1;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #d35500;
  }
.navbar-toggle {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top {
    display: none;
}



}

@media (min-width:768px){
.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-bottom {
    display: none;
}

}
```

I was close with the display: none; code. Thanks to Bender I came to realize I had to change .overflow in .navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-bottom and .navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top.

Note: for the people who want to do this too. Make sure you make 2 media queries. 1 for not displaying the top fixed navbar with a max width of 767px and 1 media query for not displaying the bottom fixed navbar with a min width of 768px.